# unable to deploy the application MobileFirst Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am new in IBM MobileFirst Hybrid mobile application. Created Project HelloWorld hybrid mobile app. when i run this application to MobileFirst server means i got following error

> Failed to deploy application 'HelloWorld' to MobileFirst Server: :
>   HTTP 403 - Forbidden

Can you tell me how to deploy the application to MobileFirst Server.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you trying this in command promt or in eclipse

Comment: i am trying this in eclipse..

Comment: has your server started

Comment: No, How will be start. i don't know how it is start.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the following:

- Try to re-install
- Verify that you do not have a firewall running (if you do, you may need to properly adjust it)
- Kill the Java process and try again

Answer (score 0):

- check your server Host name
- check if some other tools use the same MF PORT